# How do I set a store value from a $lib/foo.js file?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I know I can call `get` with `import { get } from 'svelte/store';`

Is there a way to use `set` inside a $lib file in svelte?

Comment: `set` is a method on the store itself - did you try `store.set('newValue')` ?

Answer (score 0):

I just have to call `set` on the store object:

```
import { location as loc } from '$stores/user';

loc.set(currentLocation);
```

Comment: `$loc.set()` works? Isn't it just `loc.set()`?

Comment: you're right. was thinking of read with `$loc`